# apache2 configuration for blog.example.com not working

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have  my blog running at a server with ip 10.10.10.10(not real).

There is only one virtual host for this blog on the server.

Here is the apache configuration:

VirtualHost star:80
ServerName blog.example.com
ServerAlias blog.example.com
ServerAdmin ab@example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}                  ^[^.]+.example.com$
RewriteRule   ^(.+)                         %{HTTP_HOST}$1      [C]
RewriteRule   ^([^.]+).example.com/(.*)   /var/www/$1
DirectoryIndex index.php

Directory /var/www/
  AllowOverride All
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
/Directory
/VirtualHost

My DNS blog.example.com is pointing to this ip address 10.10.10.10 .

When I load first time blog.example.com it loads correct with no problems.                But whenever i click a link it shows url like http://10.10.10.10/login.php etc.

I am a newbie. Please help me set up this.
Is there any problem with the rewrite rule ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the application generating URLS seems to be creating absolut URIs which your server is unable to handle because of your Server Configuration.

### There are two possible solutions which come to mind:

Configure the Application correctly so it either creates relative URIs or if really needed absolute URIs with the correct host.

The dirty solution would be to put a `ServerAlias` directive in place to handle this:

```
ServerAlias 10.10.10.10
```

It would be possible but not advisable to solve the problem with `mod_rewrite` as well. But this so terrible style I won't explain it.

Comment: Thanks pacey for the reply. There was problem with the application. Application was changing blog.example.com to ip address. Also mod rewrite is not required in this configuration.